# shell scripts, multiply case to call one fxn

Tags: bash, shell

i want it so a and A or b and B will call a function
anybody any idea of how to do this

```
read menu_answer
case $menu_answer in 
A)optionA;;
B)optionB;;
*)echo "oops";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options at least:

```
case $menu_answer in
    [Aa]) optionA ;;
    B|b) optionB ;;
    *) echo Oops ;;
esac
```

Instead of `case`, you could also consider `select` for a menu.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `case` in the shell is (from the bash man page)

> case *word* in [ [(] *pattern* [ | *pattern* ] ... ) list ;; ] ... esac

Where each *pattern* is matched against the expansion of *word* using the same rules as `Pathname Expansion`.

But the crucial detail is that

> [ | *pattern* ]

bit which says that you can list multiple patterns in the same match separated by pipes.

So to match both `a` and `A` in your case you can just use `a|A)` and `b|B)`.

If you have a more general desire to ignore the case of matches the `nocasematch` option exists for this purpose (from the man page again)

> If the shell option nocasematch is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters.